# In CSS background-image is not displaying image

Tags: html, css

I've literally tried everything and copied my image in every folder.

```
<div id="hero"></div>
```

```
#hero {
    height: 50vh;
    background-image: url(hero.jpg);
}
```

tried with '' with "" without .. don't know what to do anymore

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure your image location. (you just imported the image name, so your image should be in the same file of your html file)

```css
#hero {
    height: 50vh;
    background-image: url(https://cdn4.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/66/48/gradient-colors-background-vector-22266648.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="hero"></div>
```

Comment: I figured it out! After trying all sorts of possibilies the problem was the width which I haven't defined. 
Thanks!

Comment: Width is 100% by default. Not need to define

Comment: may be it's positioned absolute or floated... need to see